# Trying to get everything on One line

Tags: sql-server

Heres what I Have so far.. When I run the query it groups everything together.. I want it to get rid od the duplicates but count them ..

```
Electronic Payment  RM  Transfer to CCV2    2016-03-01 16:04:42.000 1
Electronic Payment  RM  Transfer to CCV2    2016-03-01 18:45:55.000 1
Electronic Payment  RM  Transfer to CCV2    2016-03-01 18:53:11.000 1
Electronic Payment  RM  Transfer to CCV2    2016-03-01 20:21:41.000 1
Electronic Payment  RM  Transfer to CCV2    2016-03-01 21:44:54.000 1
Electronic Payment  RM  Transfer to CCV2    2016-03-02 18:21:10.000 1
Electronic Payment  RM  Transfer to CCV2    2016-03-02 22:19:31.000 1
Electronic Payment  RM  Transfer to CCV2    2016-03-03 16:56:01.000 1
Electronic Payment  RM  Transfer to CCV2    2016-03-03 18:02:31.000 1
Electronic Payment  RM  Transfer to CCV2    2016-03-03 18:39:43.000 1
Electronic Payment  RM  Transfer to CCV2    2016-03-03 19:10:41.000
```

Heres my code I Wrote so far

```
SELECT        SR_AREA, INS_PRODUCT, RESOLUTION_CD, CREATED AS DATEADD, COUNT(*) AS DAY
FROM            S_SRV_REQ WITH (NOLOCK)         
WHERE        (dbo.fn_dstoffset(CREATED) >= '3-1-2016') AND (dbo.fn_dstoffset(CREATED) <= DATEADD(D, 1, '3-31-2016')) AND (INS_PRODUCT='RM')
GROUP BY INS_PRODUCT, RESOLUTION_CD, SR_AREA, CREATED
ORDER BY SR_AREA,INS_PRODUCT,RESOLUTION_CD DESC
```

Comment: I don't see any duplicates in your output

Comment: Since `CREATED` is in the `GROUP BY`, different creation times will cause them to be in different rows.

Comment: If you want to combine all the times together, take it out of the `GROUP BY`.

Comment: what im trying to say is I want all the 3-1-2016 to be as one and show that it was 5 payment on 3/1 instead of showing each individual payment

Comment: are you using mysql or sqlserver?

Comment: MySql doesn't use that `WITH (NOLOCK)` syntax, and the use of a `dbo` schema both strong indicate it must be Sql Server. Please pay more attention to your tags in the future.

Comment: Also: the `dbo.fn_dstoffset()` is probably **killing** your performance here. It means you can't use any indexes from your CREATED column. This kind of thing can be difference between a query taking hours and milliseconds. Also, '3-1-2016' is a **crazy** way to put a string literal in SQL.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to group by date, just use the DATE() function on `Created`
and group by DATE(Created) like this

```
SELECT        SR_AREA, INS_PRODUCT, RESOLUTION_CD, DATE(CREATED) AS DATEADD, COUNT(*) AS DAY
FROM            S_SRV_REQ WITH (NOLOCK)         
WHERE        (dbo.fn_dstoffset(CREATED) >= '3-1-2016') AND (dbo.fn_dstoffset(CREATED) <= DATEADD(D, 1, '3-31-2016')) AND (INS_PRODUCT='RM')
GROUP BY INS_PRODUCT, RESOLUTION_CD, SR_AREA, DATE(CREATED)
ORDER BY SR_AREA,INS_PRODUCT,RESOLUTION_CD DESC
```

[sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a4473/6)

This will return (with `,DATEADD ASC` added to the end of order by)

```
Electronic Payment  RM  Transfer to CCV2    March, 01 2016 00:00:00     5
Electronic Payment  RM  Transfer to CCV2    March, 02 2016 00:00:00     2
Electronic Payment  RM  Transfer to CCV2    March, 03 2016 00:00:00     4
```

It's strange that DATE() doesn't work for you...maybe try DATE_FORMAT

```
SELECT        SR_AREA, INS_PRODUCT, RESOLUTION_CD, DATE_FORMAT(CREATED,'%Y-%m-%d') AS DATEADD, COUNT(*) AS DAY
    FROM            S_SRV_REQ WITH (NOLOCK)         
    WHERE        (dbo.fn_dstoffset(CREATED) >= '3-1-2016') AND (dbo.fn_dstoffset(CREATED) <= DATEADD(D, 1, '3-31-2016')) AND (INS_PRODUCT='RM')
    GROUP BY INS_PRODUCT, RESOLUTION_CD, SR_AREA, DATE_FORMAT(CREATED,'%Y-%m-%d')
    ORDER BY SR_AREA,INS_PRODUCT,RESOLUTION_CD DESC, DATEADD ASC
```

[sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a4473/10)

**Updated** OP mentioned SQL Server instead of MySQL.
so use this instead

```
SELECT        SR_AREA, INS_PRODUCT, RESOLUTION_CD, CONVERT(VARCHAR(19),CREATED,111) AS DATEADD, COUNT(*) AS DAY
        FROM            S_SRV_REQ WITH (NOLOCK)         
        WHERE        (dbo.fn_dstoffset(CREATED) >= '3-1-2016') AND (dbo.fn_dstoffset(CREATED) <= DATEADD(D, 1, '3-31-2016')) AND (INS_PRODUCT='RM')
        GROUP BY INS_PRODUCT, RESOLUTION_CD, SR_AREA, CONVERT(VARCHAR(19),CREATED,111)
        ORDER BY SR_AREA,INS_PRODUCT,RESOLUTION_CD DESC, DATEADD ASC
```

[sqlfiddle for sql server](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/a4473/1)

Comment: I keep getting DATE is not a recognized built in function name

Comment: added a query to use DATE_FORMAT() instead of DATE() at bottom my answer ..try that one and let me know

Comment: I bet @mel is using sqlserver, not mysql.

Comment: No that still not working. Im using  SQL Server Management Studio

Comment: if you're using SQL Server try `CONVERT(VARCHAR(19),CREATED,111)` instead of DATE_FORMAT()

Comment: **NO**, don't use CONVERT()! Then you're grouping on strings, and doing lots of unnecessary culture-aware formatting that are _much_ slower and just might even break things if you happen to be running with some weird culture settings. It's probably okay in this case, but it's still not the better option. Instead, `CAST(CREATED AS DATE)` to remove the time portion.